# Mesa Compile results in unusable drivers?

Tags: debian, opengl

I built mesa from git on debian wheezy following the instructions [here](http://x.debian.net/howto/build-mesa.html). I had to build `libdrm_intel` from source as well, as the version in the repo was too old.

I'm on a T500 with integrated graphics, it has an Intel 4500MHD

To actually build mesa, I did

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --enable-driglx-direct \
            --enable-gles1 \
            --enable-gles2 \
            --enable-glx-tls \
            --with-dri-driverdir=/usr/lib/dri \
            --with-egl-platforms='drm x11' \
            --with-dri-drivers=i965 \
            --disable-dri3 \
            --with-gallium-drivers=""
```

then `sudo make`

The drivers end up in `/home/mark/mesa.git/lib/`, and I export that where the instructions say to `export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=lib`.

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep so$
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/i965_dri.so
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
```

`/home/mark/mesa.git/lib/i965_dri.so` exists, but it still says unable to load driver.

```
$ ll /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/i965_dri.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 39M Jan  4 15:57 /home/mark/mesa.git/lib/i965_dri.so*
```

If I don't export the new lib directory, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so` is what is used. If I replace that with the newly compiled version, it starts failing to load.

What can I do to figure out why the newly compiled version doesn't work?

Comment: Did you run `sudo make install`?

Comment: @eyoung100 It didn't say to do that, but it _seems_ to have worked(The glxinfo grep seems to have loaded i965_dri.so fine.). Will report back once I can actually test it. If it does work, I'll also contact the owner of the guide I used.

Comment: Great!!  Glad I could help